# how to update array of objects with other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
const [data , setData] = useState([
{
  id:1,
  name : "Walnuts",
  checked:false
},
{
  id:2,
  name:"cashew nut",
  checked : false,
},
{
  id:3,
  name:"pista",
  checked : false,
},
{
  id:4,
  name : "almond",
  checked:false
},
{
  id:5,
  name:"beans",
  checked : false,
},
{
  id:6,
  name:"banana",
  checked : false,
},
{
  id:7,
  name:"apple",
  checked : false,
},
{
  id:8,
  name:"mango",
  checked : false,
},
{
  id:9,
  name:"potato",
  checked : false,
},
{
  id:10,
  name:"carrot",
  checked : false,
},
])
```

I am having the above data and arrays

```
const fruits = ["banana","apple","mango"]
const nuts = ["walnuts","pista","cashew nut"]
const veg = ["beans","carrot","potato"]
```

and I have 3 radio buttons like fruits, nuts and veg.

If the user selects fruits all the fruits with the name in the fruits array should be checked is equal to true in the data array of objects
can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Try filtering your array

Comment: I would suggest adding a `type` in your array instead of maintaining multiple arrays. `{
  id:4,
  name : "almond",
  checked: false,
  type: 'nut'
}`
and then add a filter on type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approaches can be like :-

```
function updateData(array)
{
const newData = data.map((item)=>{
 if(array.includes(item.name))
  return {...item,checked:true}
 else 
  return {...item,checked:false};
})
setData(newData);
}
```

**Explanation :** You're looping over all the `items` in your `data` array and then if your `array` **(fruits,nuts or veg)** include that value your just return a new `item` object with `checked` set to `true` else with `checked` set to `false`. The resultant array would be a new one since you're using `.map` and now you can set it as your state.

Although this is less performant with complexity of **O(length of data array * length of fruits array)**. A better approach could be have a `Set` of `fruits` where you check like so :-

```
function updateData(set)
{
const newData = data.map((item)=>{
 if(set.has(item.name)){
  return {...item,checked:true}
 else 
  return {...item,checked:false};
})
setData(newData);
}
```

An even better approach could be changing the existing data-structure of your `data` array to include one more property like `kind` or `type` based on which you can only change those items whose `kind/type` matches with selected option from **radio button**.

Answer (score 1):

Do you meen like this?

```
data.filter(item => {
 if(fruits.includes(item.name)){
  item.checked = true;
 }
 return data
})
```